# How to check the vsyscall mode

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, configuration-files, system-calls

I am struggling to find out how to check how the [vsyscall] table is configured (to native or emulate). The setting should be set in a variable called `vsyscall_mode`. Can anyone shed any light on how to check this setting?

By re-running `cat /proc/self/maps` I have observed that the memory mapped area for [vsyscall] does not change, which the [vdso] does. Does this mean that the setting for vsyscall is set to native?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vsyscall mode is set in kernel configuration so you can be able to choose between native and emulation.

for fish-shell:

```
cat /usr/src/linux-headers-(uname -r)/.config | grep VSYSCALL
```

for bash:

```
cat /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config | grep VSYSCALL
```

output on debian 8 (as example):

```
CONFIG_GENERIC_TIME_VSYSCALL=y
CONFIG_X86_VSYSCALL_EMULATION=y
```

Comment: There is a [`vsyscall` command-line option](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/abfbb29297c27e3f101f348dc9e467b0fe70f919/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#L5535-L5553). Looking at the kernel headers does not tell you the current value.

Answer (score -1):

Usually available in the /proc/config.gz file, it will contain the current kernel config.